# Delete last two lines of stdout using c shell?

Tags: linux, shell, printf, csh

I want to create a little animation in the stdout of the terminal using **printf**.
So far I figured out how to replace the last line with

```
#!/bin/csh -f        
printf "text1"
printf "text2"
sleep 1
printf "\r replaced text2"
```

How do I replace both lines?

```
printf "\r\r replace text1"
```

does not work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `cuu1` terminfo capability to move the cursor up.

```
printf "foobar"
tput cuu1
printf "baz"
```

Comment: Note that `tput cuu1` will move the cursor up one row, but it will stay on the same column. Depending on what you're doing, you might want to print another `"\r"`, or perhaps use whatever `tput` code moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. Note also that if the new text is shorter than the old text, it won't replace all of it: `printf "original\rNEW\n"` prints `NEWginal`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignacios answer brought me on the right track! Thanks!!
Nevertheless:

```
    tput cuu N
```

sets your cursor **N** lines back.